# Using extra repositories in Virtualmin

Tags: repository

I fully set up Virtualmin and I was playing with the automic repo. I accidentally left it enabled and updated these packages:

`May 23 11:06:11 Updated: spamassassin-3.3.2-7.el6.art.x86_64`

`May 23 11:06:26 Updated: clamav-0.97.8-11.el6.art.x86_64`

But there are also other updates (php, geoIp etc). What is best practice? Update these packages or should I remove the updates and revert to the original files from the Virtualmin repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtualmin uses the same files and standards for configuration of all services and, at first, everything should work fine with updated versions (it can even recognize the configuration you have done manually).

In a rare case, you should get some non-expected behavior and, only in this case, you should remove the updates.

Comment: I can confirm as I have used the automic repo for almost a year now ;)